# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null getting this error in spring boot for eureka server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, netflix-eureka

```
    ava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
 : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    2022-01-31 19:29:43.769  WARN 15760 --- [           main]t has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3463)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3434)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
     java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    2022-01-31 19:29:43.888  INFO 15760 --- [           main]  : Stopping service [Tomcat]
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 (SpringApplication.java:775) ~     at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
   (TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 failed to start
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Share the POM file, application.properties and other files. I wonder how to answer, which isn't clear..

Comment: @ZakirHussain sorry about that im new to stack for posting question so my question is about when i'm using 2.6.3 org.springframework.boot then the config server is working fine but when i degraded to 2.X.X org.springframework.boot and also tried to add some servers like greenwich. and other searched servers and its not working for some its throwing exception and some its not fetching properties config from git and its not throwing any error im kind of confuse here did you get it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.